# Windows Live Writer replacement for a Mac user

Tags: osx, google-apps

Our CEO has used [Windows Live Writer](http://writer.live.com/) for the past year and really likes it. However he recently updated his setup to use a Mac, and now needs another blogging tool. He's willing to try a few if needed, but doesn't really know which one's he should try out.

The blog is hosted on blogger.com, and in the past he had used the blogger.com web tools but never really liked them.

Any recommendations for replacement software he can try?

Comment: Which features does he need? (He’s probably not needing an exact copy of Windows Live Writer; and many might not know this tool in the first place.)

Comment: Thanks @unor, it's really that he likes the simplicity of WLW.  His blog is basic, he likes to right a bunch of text, put a small, left justified image of the current book he's reading, and wrap text about that book around the image.  WLW was just really, really easy for him to use, and any formatting he did seemed to stick.  So if there's a general, easy to use Mac app he can use, just name it and he can give it a whirl.  I just don't know any Mac application's whatsoever. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Good news and bad news (and potentially good news).

Good news - So we never found a replacement.  Instead, we installed Parallels on his macbook, installed Win 7, installed Windows Live Writer, and created a shortcut to WLW on his Mac "desktop" (or iDesktop or whatever they call it).  So when he double clicks the icon, Win 7 spins up in the background and opens the software.  The initial run takes about 10 seconds to open the software.  Subsequent requests take maybe a second or 2.  Over complicated?  Slightly.  Expensive?  A little, a license for Parallels ran us 60 bucks.  But hey, the guy signs our pay checks, so whatever it takes...

Bad News - Google recently (December '15) killed off the authentication method for bloggers using their blogger service via Windows Live Writer.  So, as of this time, you can no longer user Windows Live Writer to write blogs for Google Blogger.  Keep Reading...

Potentially Good News - WLW authentication was killed off because Microsoft open sourced Open Live Writer, a community based project to maintain and enhance what the world has deemed one of it's favorite blog writing tools. Google caught wind of this and phoned up their bridge troll, answered his questions thrice, and had him permanently disable the old authentication method. The new software is on version 0.4.2 or something small like that currently, so it's still a few months away from not throwing up when you try to add an image, but in the not too distant future Open Live Writer will be a viable solution for writing blogger.com blogs on a variety of devices... I wouldn't be surprised if it eventually has it's own Mac install rather than requiring Parallels even.. but only time will tell.

Hope this helps...